# migrator.net vs fluentmigrator vs migsharp

Tags: database, migration

I am currently investigating possible options of a migration framework/tool. I like the idea of ruby migrations on which the above frameworks are based.

So I am asking for your experience, opinions and maybe a comparison between them. Are you using them in production?

---

thanks for responses. The goal of this question was to get a feeling about which tools is used most in the developer community but it seems that migrations are not a hot topic here.

Anyway, I have decided to go with MigSharp as the codebase seem to be pretty clean and it is quite easy to handle and had build in support for MS SQL CE. Second runner up would have been FluentMigrator where I was not able to produce a working example for compact edition.

Cheers

Comment: Classic gorila vs shark http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I use FluentMigrator in production, and am a longtime contributor to FM. I think your question is to general; be more specific. Also, FM has a google group which is fairly active if you want FM information.

FM is derived from migrator.net, as I recall. It uses a fluent-syntax, and supports multiple databases. We have taken some inspiration from rails migrations, but it's definitely not a port. Worth checking out.

One thing I've learned is not to put your migrations in the same assembly as you app code. Separate them into a migration assembly, and use that for migrating your databases.

Also, you should always work on multiple environments to avoid problems with migrations run straight against production. I always have at least a development and production environment, and most of the time there is a testing environment as well.

Answer (score 3):

I use mig#.

It works well, but you will need to have some guidelines for usage - as migrations can get complicated.

We use sequence number on the end of our migrations rather than a date-time stamp. This is because we don't know when the date time stamp was set (when they begun the source code change-set; just before committing; some time inbetween) different developers could use different approaches.

Names such as Migration_0000034.cs give you plenty of space.

Comment: Are you saying that migrations get complicated with Mig# or in general?

Comment: BTW, the manual to Mig# can be found here: https://github.com/dradovic/MigSharp/wiki

Answer (score 0):

At this point, I would stick with migrator.net. I like the promise of FluentMigrator, but it seems to not have any better active development than migrator.net (see the issues and pull requests that have languished on their github site).

There is also no easy way to do an ExecuteScalar(). I'd add it, but I don't want to create my own fork, and I see no reason that a pull request would actually land in the master. (Execute.WithConnection is an Action so it will fire on demand rather than when I need it to fire)

So for me, I'm heading back to migrator.net.